# Evaluating DISA-STIG for Windows 7 returns only "notchecked"

Tags: windows, windows-7, openscap

I've downloaded the `DISA_STIG` for Windows 7 from https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_7/ (XML version) and tried to evaluate my desktop with OSCAP 1.3.0 for windows, with the command:

```
oscap xccdf eval --profile MAC-3_Public --results windows7.html disa-stig-windows7.xml
```

The OSCAP tool didn't complain about the file, but all checks returned the result `notchecked` with the warning:

> Skipping rule that requires an unregistered check system or incorrect content reference to evaluate. Please consider providing a valid SCAP/OVAL instead of _chk` (where check_name is the name of the check within the xccdf file)

What should I do in order to run a successful evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

the XML provided in the reference doesn't contain automated checks (e.g.: OVAL), it seems there are only manual checks.
Looking at `system` attributes of `check` elements, I noted something strange, it seems to be defining an ID for the check, instead of defining the checking system to use, as every rule has a different checking system.

What you need is a benchmark with automated checks.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input! I´m new to SCAP, so I would have never noticed the "system" attributes. Do you know any other source of Windows 7 checklists? Aside from this one that I´ve mentioned in my original question I´ve only found references to checklists at NIST´s Computer Security Resource Center (CSRC - https://csrc.nist.gov) but they are currently not available due to the lapse in government funding (as shown in https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/United-States-Government-Configuration-Baseline/data/content/scap/oval510/Win7-2.0.5.1.zip).